# What means an empty element in an array and why it has taken into account in the length if theoretically it does not exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I add a element to the array in a higher position than its length

[image]

I wonder if is there a way to access or delete this empty elements, I think it can waste memory

Comment: No, it's not wasting memory. Only the elements that are assigned use memory, see the linked question.

Comment: You could just not write to a position larger than the length of the array.. that is why `push` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing this, you create a ["sparse array"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch07s03.html). The items in between the non-null entries contain `undefined`. As such, the memory footprint is negligible. You cannot delete them. If you don't like this behavior, just don't create sparse arrays.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering non sparse/dense elements, you could use a callback which returns for every element `true`.

Maybe this link helps a bit to understand the mechanic of a sparse array: [JavaScript: sparse arrays vs. dense arrays](http://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html).

```js
let array = new Array(99999),
    nonsparse;

array[30] = undefined;

nonsparse = array.filter(_ => true);

console.log(nonsparse);
console.log(nonsparse.length);
```

Comment: But this really doesn't address the question. *I wonder if is there a way to access or delete this empty elements, I think it can waste memory*

Comment: do you mention the memory part? if yes, the yes ... i like tautologies, but *"I wonder if is there a way to ... delete this empty elements"*

Comment: I mentioned both parts. Your answer just shows how to create a second array with the non-undefined data from the first. It doesn't address either points.